# Retain the values after refeshing the page

Tags: javascript, ruby

How do I retain the value of like count even after refreshing the page in ruby on rails?

```
<p> 
<input  type="button" value="Like" id="countButton" />(<span id="displayCount">0</span>) 

<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 0;
    var button = document.getElementById("countButton");
    var display = document.getElementById("displayCount");

    button.onclick = function() {
        count++;
        display.innerHTML = count;
    }
</script>
</p>
```

The above code increments the value of like each time we hit the like button. After refreshing the page the value of count be comes `0`. What to do to retain the values of like after refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Web pages are stateless so every time you refresh the page, any values will be lost unless you specifically save them. If you want to save them forever, you will need to create a database table that saves the number of likes. Each time the like button is clicked you will need to save the new value to the d/b.

You will need a database backed model for whatever it is that is being liked. You may want to look at the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), [active record](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) and learn about [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [RESTful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do with the counter.

- If it is user related, you can store the value in the user's session
  like this : `session[:counter] = 2`.
- If the counter should be shared between all users, you will have to create a new field in your database to store it.